# Can't get styles from event.target in React

Tags: css, reactjs, events

I am trying to take `left` and `width` styles from an element, when the pointer hovers a `li`, but all I am getting are empty strings.

```
<div>
    <div className="categories-list-container">
      <ul className="categories-list">
        {categories.map((category, index) => {
          return (<li onClick={handleCategoryFocus} key={index}>{category}</li>)
        })}
      </ul>
      <span className="select-bar" style={underlineCoordinates}/>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The function I am using

```
const handleCategoryFocus = (event:any) => {
  console.log(event.target);
  const left = event.target.style.left + event.target.width/2;
  setUnderlineCoordinates({width: event.target.width, left: left})
```

}

Is there another way to do that?

Comment: Are you looking for [offsetWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetWidth) and [offsetLeft](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetLeft)?

Comment: So you're getting empty strings from `event.target` or the styles?

Comment: Are you certain that the styles have been set on the li element you are looking at? Who would have set them? Without seeing your full code it's not possible to tell. as @JacobSmit has suggested you probably are more interested in the values given by offsetWidth etc.

Comment: indeed, the offsetWidth did the job, but I still got nothing from offsetLeft. In  the end I did use event.target.getBoundingClientRect().x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I used event.target.getBoundingClientRect() to get the coordinates of the element, which worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the targets style from event.currentTarget.

---

**event.currentTarget** tells us on which element the event was attached or the element whose eventListener triggered the event.

**event.target** tells where the event started.